# Show success message when deleted (query succesfull)

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to show a succes message when a field gets deleted succefully.

I already have a confirmation alert that's working, but now I want to echo a message (or display it with js) that the query was succesfull.

When I tried the if part it always shows post verwijdert (post deleted in dutch), but I want it to show after the confirmation alert.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Verwijderen</title>
<header><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">


    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
            function delpage(id, title)
            {
               if (confirm("Weet je zeker dat je '" + title + "' wilt verwijderen?"))
               {
                  window.location.href = '?delpage=' + id;
               }
            }
        </script>
        </header>

<body>
    <nav>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="../index.php" target=_blank"">Bekijk site</a></li>
    <li><a href="voegtoe.php">Toevoegen</a></li>
    <li><a href="verwijder.php">Verwijderen</a></li>
    <li><a href="?logout">Uitloggen</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>

<div id="verwijder">

        <?php
    include '../includes/includes.php';

    $blogPosts = GetBlogPosts();

foreach ($blogPosts as $post)  
{  
}  

//run if a page deletion has been requested
if(isset($_GET['delpage'])){

    $delpage = $_GET['delpage'];
    $delpage = mysql_real_escape_string($delpage);
    $sql1 = mysql_query("DELETE FROM blog_posts WHERE id = '$delpage'");
    header('Location:verwijder.php');
    exit();
}




$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog_posts ORDER BY id DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($sql)) 
{
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<h1><td>$row->title</td></h1>";
        if($row->id == 0)
        { //home page verberg delete link
        } 
        else 
        {
            // delete functie waarbij een alert word weergegeven of je dit zeker wil
            echo "<td><a class='link' href=\"javascript:delpage('$row->id','$row->title');\">Verwijder</a></td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
}

if ($sql1 == !false)
{
    echo '<h1>Post verwijdert</h1>';
}
else
{
    echo 'test';    
}
?>

</div>
```

Comment: You can't put elements outside `<html>` tag. Isn't semantically correct.

Comment: Also what you want to do could be done via ajax or print a javascript code under a php condition (like query was executed).

Comment: Doesn't metters its `display` property, it just can't be there. Well, it's your html anyway.

Comment: Yeah I know that it can be done, the question is how.

Comment: you're telling the browser to navigate to a new URL on delete, so what does *that* page do? That's where you're going to be showing whether or not the deletion worked. Right now you're making the script `exit(0)` on delpage, instead of generating the rest of the content that generates the HTML for saying "it worked" vs. "it didn't work"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep the result of delete in `$_SESSION` and do like  the following.But remembaer before using sessionyou must do `session_start();`

```
//run if a page deletion has been requested
if(isset($_GET['delpage'])){
    $delpage = $_GET['delpage'];
    $delpage = mysql_real_escape_string($delpage);
    $sql1    = mysql_query("DELETE FROM blog_posts WHERE id = '$delpage'");
    if($sql1)
      $_SESSION['delete'] = 1;
    header('Location:verwijder.php');
    exit();
}
```

Then in `verwijder.php`

```
if(isset($_SESSION['delete']) && $_SESSION['delete']){
   //Show success message of delete here
   unset($_SESSION['delete']);
}
```